# Not getting update notification in mobile for my Android Application

Tags: android, google-play

For app version 1.0, I am having 4 apks(supporting different screen resolution).In manifest for 1.0, min sdk was 7 with different compatible screen filters. Again for app version 1.1, I have put 4 apks(supporting different screen resolution). In manifest 1.1, min sdk was 8 with different compatible screen filters. Now in developer console that time while uploading apks I didn't faced any problem. All 8 apks were in active mode. Yesterday I have updated another 4 apks for version 1.2, in manifest min sdk and filters are same as it is for version 1.1 . Now that I got this error: **Error: APK version 3404400,2802221,2401211 supports all the same devices as other APKs with higher versions. It would not be served. Please deactivate an APK.**   So I have deactivate the older version 1.1 apks. But still in mobile I am not getting the update notification. Is it is required to deactivate all the apks except the new ones,i.e.,4 apks of version 1.2 . Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by de-activating all older version apks